# Why vim does not recognize new runlevel7 in inittab?

Tags: init.d, runlevel, rc.d

Mainly for test purpose, I wish to modify `/etc/inittab` and add a new runlevel to my system (`/etc/rc7.d`). I have not save my modification yet, because I'm confused by `Vim` behavior. Indeed, the editor seems to not recognized the new runlevel as... a new runlevel (like `rc 2,3,4` and so on). Here is a screen capture :

[image: <code>Vim</code> screen capture]

As you can see, `Vim` hi-lights in red the number seven and it "lowlights" the address of the config file from yellow to standard green (like thing which are not particular recognized). I'm wondering why does `Vim` don't act with the new runlevel as it was a standard one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like Vim is smart enough to give you a clue as to what the problem is! That's interesting.

The problem is that there is no such runlevel as `7`. The valid run levels are `s` (or `S`), `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, and `6`. According to the manpage of my copy of `init` there also exist also pseudo-runlevels `a`, `b`, and `c` though I have never heard of those before.

**EDIT**: It seems that runlevels 7 through 9 *do* actually exist, but they are undocumented. I read the `init` source code under Debian wheezy to confirm it's true! Thanks for pointing that out.

So it turns out that what you are trying to do should actually work. But it's no surprise that Vim doesn't know about it since it's... well... undocumented. I would add also that it might not be very portable.

Comment: yep, true, there is not runlevel7 by default. But I assume I can add one if I would like to? This blogpost details the easy way : https://deadend.wordpress.com/howtos/howto-how-to-create-a-new-runlevel/ I have already created the new rc7.d folder. What do you think?

Comment: Well, yeah, I guess you could create a new one, but you'd have to modify and recompile `init` to do it! As `init` exists right now, only the runlevels I stated in my answer actually exist. Read the manpages for `init` and `inittab` to see for yourself.

Comment: I just had a look at the blog post. I'm surprised someone wrote that. I believe it's complete fiction. I wonder if the author tested it at all. Runlevel 7 just doesn't exist. Adding a line in the configuration file does not magically make it exist. Or maybe it does with some variant implementation of `init` I'm not familiar with?

Comment: Finally in inittab manpage they tell about A,B,C (don't know neither what it is really). More interesting, in init manpage, they tell about runlevel 7 to 9 that "are available without being very documented, because traditional UNIXs don't use them". I'm on debian wheezy. I guess adding from scratch a "new" runlevel 7 before have a clear understanding on how theses kinda secret runlevels work really, is NOT a very good idea u_u thx for make me think

Comment: Thanks for correcting me about undocumented runlevels `7`, `8`, and `9`. I edited my answer.

Comment: The additional runlevels don't work any different from normal runlevels. The fact of the matter is only the initscripts really know the difference anyway. As far as init is concerned, 0 is just another level.

Answer (score 7):

From `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/inittab.vim`:

```
syn match inittabRunLevels "[0-6A-Ca-cSs]\+" contained nextgroup=inittabColonAction,inittabError
```

So yes, vim considers only 0-6, and both upper-and lowercase `a` `b` `c` `s` letters as valid runlevels.